# String from readdir() function cannot be manipulate

Tags: php

I have two functions below

```
function ListFiles($dir) {
    if($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        $files = array();
        $topics = array();
        $inner_files = array();
        while($file = readdir($dh)) {
            if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file[0] != '.') {
                array_push($topics, $file);
                if(is_dir($dir . "/" . $file)) {
                    $inner_files = ListFiles($dir . "/" . $file);
                    if(is_array($inner_files)) $files = array_merge($files, $inner_files);
                } else {
                    array_push($files, $dir . "/" . $file);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
        $topics = array();
        $i = 0;

        foreach ($files as $file) {
//wrong result
            $topics[] = getTopicFromPath($file);

//correct result
//$topics[] = getTopicFromPath("/Users/Unknown/Sites/sample/training/topic/acq/19ddb673359747ee9095.txt")
        }
        return $topics;
    }
}

function getTopicFromPath($path){
//$path = /Users/Unknown/Sites/sample/training/topic/acq/19ddb673359747ee9095.txt

    $string1 = substr($path,strpos($path,"topic/"));
//$string1 = topic/acq/19ddb673359747ee9095.txt

    $string2 = str_replace("topic/", "", $string1);
//$string2  = acq/19ddb673359747ee9095.txt

    $string3 = strstr($string2, '/', true);
//$string3 = null
//expecting $string3 = 'acq'

    return $string3;;
}
```

The problem is getTopicFromPath($path) cannot parse string from readdir() method. But if I put a pure string the result is correct. Please check the code to be clear.

What I want to do is get the file path, save its parent folder as topic.

Using another method to get the file maybe fix the problem. But I'm curious what is wrong with those functions?

Comment: Er... could you share what the problem is?

Comment: `if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file[0] != '.')` could just be `if($file[0] != '.')`

Comment: Why not [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

Comment: So old, use glob() man

Comment: define "cannot be manipulate"

Comment: $topics which is returned is an array not a string ?

Comment: @Sam : I don't need file details, I just need the path

Comment: @Adder : I want to put a substring from $file into $topics[]

Comment: Use ResursiveDirectoryIterator

Comment: Or glob if you just need the filename

Comment: Check whether mb_strlen equals strlen? You need to have multibyte characters configured in php.ini though.

Comment: @Adder : I think it's enabled. From phpInfo() I got : Zend Multibyte Support provided by mbstring

Comment: Cool, please output strlen and mb_strlen of $path in the getTopicFromPath function.

Comment: @Adder:
same length of the string....
btw, this not happens when I use RecursiveDirectoryIterator, I'm curious! need to know this kind of thing

Comment: The simplest explanation would be that the string actually has a double // after topic: /Users/Unknown/Sites/sample/training/topic//acq/19ddb673359747ee9095.tx

Comment: no... I check it many times no double slash in the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your code needs to be cleaned and simplified.

1 - In your function getTopicFromPath(), if *string3* is NULL then the '/' has not been found in *string2*. 
Maybe you're under Windows and your directory separator is '\' instead of '/' ?

To get rid of these problems, use the native **DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR** constant.

2 - Obviously, this function tries to find the directory name of your file *$path*. 
Then you'd better use directory related functions and avoid too specific coding. 
Too specific often means context dependent and fragile.

Anyway, I'd rewrite your function in two lines, and two flavours :

```
function getTopicFromPath($path) {
    $dir = dirname($path);
    return substr($dir, strrpos($dir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) + 1);
}
```

or

```
function getTopicFromPath($path) {
    $dir = dirname($path);
    return basename($dir);
}
```

3 - *getTopicFromPath()* is called within a recursive function. Many entries will be processed several times. That's redundant.

You should divide your process in two independent steps : first retrieve the full pathes of your files, then trim them. You'll gain reusability and robustness.

4 - Eventually, you should clean your *ListFile()* function :

```
closedir($dh);
$topics = array();
$i = 0;
```

`$topics = array()` means that the above assignments into this variable are useless as they will be overloaded.

`$i` is unused in its scope.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clean it up because I'm still doing some test
Thanks for the advice :)